# Duplicate records created on page load vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I trying to figure out why my code in inserting two records into the database when it executes? the `CreateEnrollment` Sub executes fine, however the results insert 2 sometimes 3 records ranging from 1-10 seconds apart, depending on remote server load. I first thought it might be the `IsPostBack` problem but adding the `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then` did not resolve.

```
Dim FailedMessage As String = "This COPDI (On-Line) user failed: "
Dim PassedMessage As String = "This COPDI (On-Line) user passes: "
Dim ClassName As String = "COPDI (FAILED)"
Dim SendMailAddress As String = "myEmailAddress.com"
Dim SubsiteConnString As String = "Subsite_appSettings"
Dim MainsiteConnString As String = "SubsiteConn"
Dim RecordsReturned As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim UserName As String = User.Identity.Name()
    Dim userID As Integer = GetUID(UserName)
    Dim ClassDate As Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToShortDateString
    Dim ClassTime As String = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3). ToShortTimeString 
    
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    
        If Request.QueryString("code") = 1111 Then
            RecordsReturned = RecordExist(UserName)
            CreateEnrollment(UserName, ClassDate, ClassTime, ClassName, userID)
            UpdateLastActivityDate(UserName)
        
            If RecordsReturned < 3 Then
                Response.Redirect("~/transcript.aspx" & "?code=" & RecordsReturned)
            Else  
                Response.Redirect("~/transcript.aspx" & "?code=" & "more_than_three")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub CreateEnrollment(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal ClassDate As Date, ByVal ClassTime As String, ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal UID As Integer)
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(SubsiteConnString)
    Dim conn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO EnrollmentsTbl (" & _
    "[UserName],[SubmitTime],[ClassTime],[ClassDate],[Enrolled],[ClassName],[Instructor],[DateCompleted],[Completed],[WaitListed],[UID]) " & _
    "VALUES (@UserName, @SubmitTime, @ClassTime, @ClassDate, @Enrolled, @ClassName, @Instructor, @DateCompleted, @Completed, @WaitListed, @UID) "

    Dim comm As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmitTime", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToString())
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassTime", ClassTime)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassDate", ClassDate)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrolled", True)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassName", ClassName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", "On-line")
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCompleted", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToString)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed", False)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaitListed", False)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UID)
    Dim result As Integer = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    
Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
Finally
        conn.Close()
End Try  
End Sub


Public Function RecordExist(ByVal username As String) As Integer
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(SubsiteConnString)
    Dim conn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EnrollmentsTbl " & _
        "WHERE [UserName] = """ & username & """ AND ClassName LIKE """ & ClassName & """ AND [Completed] = 0 AND [Enrolled] = -1"
    Dim DBCommand As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
   Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim RecordCount As Integer = CInt(DBCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        conn.Close()
        Return RecordCount
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Function


Public Function GetUID(ByVal username As String) As Integer
    Dim xUserName As String = User.Identity.Name()

    If (Not xUserName="") Then
 
    Dim objConn As Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim objCmd As Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim objRdr As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim userAN As String
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TechTrainingConn").ToString
    objConn = New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    objCmd = New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM UsersDataTbl WHERE [UserName] = """ & xUserName & """", objConn)
        Try
            objConn.Open()
            objRdr = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

            While objRdr.Read()
                userAN = objRdr.Item("UID")
            End While
            objRdr.Close()
            objConn.Close()

            Session("userID") = userAN
            Return userAN
                'Response.Write(Session("userAN") & " - " & xUserName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        Finally
            objConn.Close()
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: after trying re-create this for testing, it appears its only doing this on the remote hosted web server (not under my control) Ugg

Answer (score 0):

What aspx page is this supporting? I noticed you have a redirect to transcript.aspx, is this code for that page? If so that would explain the multiple page loads. Response.Redirect is not a postback so it's going to fall into recordReturned and CreateEnrollment methods again, especially if you are passing the &code=1111 in the URL querystring

Comment: This page is called from a test taking page if the test scores is less than 70% - the code=1234 is just to indicate a failed test trigger to create a record in the DB of a failed attempt. The user never sees this page as it makes the database entry and then redirects to a page showing their class transcripts - what are you saying about the redirect triggering another entry?

Comment: the code for test taking page maybe worth sharing, that maybe where its somehow calling this page multiple times. Have you tried placing a break point on page load then running your program to see when page load hits and how many times?

Comment: Actually I’m not using the test taking page to troubleshoot this,  I’m just simply running http://this-page.aspx?code=1111 ; so that rules out the previous page...